# Get data between each 5 year in SQL Server (like 1990-1995, 1995-2000, 2000-2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `orders` with columns `orderid` and `OrderDate`.

I want to get data in batches of 5 years, like total orders between 1990-1995, 1995-2000, 2000-2005 etc in SQL Server.

For example :

```
Period          Orders
1990-1995       4500
1995-2000       7000
2000-2005       9000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in which period data for 1995 from your example will go?

Comment: Is `Orders` field contains price of an order or what.?

Comment: @Vishal thanks for response, yes it contains other columns too, but I just want to count number of order for each 5 year.

Comment: @Anand Ok..I added a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a clear syntax, using one subquery:

```
SELECT CAST(T.YearDivision * 5 AS nchar(4)) + N' - ' + CAST(T.YearDivision * 5 + 4 AS nchar(4)) AS YearRange, SUM(T.TotalCount) AS TotalOrders
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(Date) / 5 AS YearDivision, Date, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY Date
) T
GROUP BY YearDivision
```

I think you are overlapping the year ranges repeating the years at the end and the start of each consecutive range. I remove that overlapping here.

This are the results for this query on sample table of one of my databases:

```
YearRange   TotalOrders
----------- -----------
2005 - 2009 2680
2010 - 2014 1395
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Anand have you tried my solution? it's just one group by instead of two

Comment: @Jaime how can I vote and accept it as answer, please guide. Thanks Roman, I also tried your solution and it is also working, but don't know difference between both answer.

Comment: @Anand I think it's just cleaner to read and to modify in the future, but you're free to use any solution you want :)

Comment: Well, I don't think a CTE-based solution is cleaner to read, since it requires understanding the CTE concept. It is not complicated, but I find a subquery here more suitable and understandable. On the other hand, @RomanPekar you are overlapping the final year of each range with te initial year of the next range. Just change the +5 by  +4 :)

Comment: @Jaime I think it's really subjective then (But for me it's obviously cleaner especially if you need to have more than one subquery/cte). Don't need to change +5 to +4, my query gives exact result OP wants, by yes, it's very easy to change name of the group :)

Answer (score 0):

you can group by YEAR function - this will do groupping by each year, like:

```
select YEAR(d), sum(...)
from table
group by YEAR(d)
```

if you want to combine several years into one - consider simple math:

```
select FLOOR(YEAR(d)/5)*5, sum(...)
from table
group by FLOOR(YEAR(d)/5)
```

with this group your will have [1990-1994] [1995-1999] [2000-2004] ([ and ] means inclusively)

if you want to change it to have [1991-1995] [1996-2000] etc, use:

```
select FLOOR((YEAR(d)+1)/5)*5-1, sum(...)
from table
group by FLOOR((YEAR(d)+1)/5)
```

Comment: Thanks llya for quick response, But I am not getting your point. Can you please explain in some detail ? My table name is orders and it has 2 columns orderid and orderdate.

Comment: @Anand my point: you need to summarize several orders within one group, you said that you need groups like "1990-1995", "1995-2000", for me it looks like orders from 1995 will go in both groups, ie duplicated, but it is obviously wrong for finances, so I suppose you need either 1990-1994 and 1995-1999 or 1991-1995 and 1996-2000

Comment: @llya, I have just tried "select YEAR(OrderDate), sum(OrderID)
from [Max].[dbo].[Orders]
group by FLOOR((YEAR(OrderDate)+1)/5)" but getting error:- "Column 'Max.dbo.Orders.OrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.", thanks

Comment: @IlyaBursov actually you don't need to assume that group 1990-1995 include data from 1995 year, it could be treate like exclusive end point

Comment: @RomanPekar I understand, so I provided 2 solutions for different exclusive points

Comment: @llya, I am trying your solution like "select YEAR(OrderDate), sum(OrderID)
from Orders
group by FLOOR(YEAR(OrderDate)/5)", but it is giving error :- "Column 'Orders.OrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.", Can you help with this ?

Comment: @Anand updating answer, as soon as we use GROUP BY, we have to use the same field/function is SELECT, so just change `select YEAR(OrderDate)` to exact copy of GROUP by: `select FLOOR(YEAR(OrderDate)/5)`, but you can add *5 to it, to have proper year displayed, like: `select FLOOR(YEAR(OrderDate)/5) * 5`

Comment: @llya, I tried "select FLOOR(YEAR(OrderDate)/5)*5, sum(orderid)
from [Orders]
group by FLOOR(YEAR(OrderDate)/5)" but now getting "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."

Comment: @Anand just for test remove `sum(orderid)` from query, is it the same error? (don't have ms sql installed, so cannot check on real db)

Comment: Now no error, it is giving 1 column (No column name) and 2 rows with values 2005 and 2010.

Comment: @Anad ok, so it's sum overflow, try to change `sum(orderid)` to `sum(cast(orderid as bigint))`

Comment: @Anand summarize all ordersid manually and you will see that it is correct result, if you want count - use `count` instead of `sum`

Comment: @llya, Sorry my mistake, I have to use count instead of sum and now result is correct. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives you desired output - see sql fiddle below:

```
with cte as (
   select
       (year(OrderDate) / 5) * 5 as y
   from orders
)
select
    cast(y as nvarchar(4)) + '-' + cast(y + 5 as nvarchar(4)) as Period,
    count(*) as Orders
from cte
group by y
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41a7e/1)</kbd>**

Here I'm using cte so you don't have to repeat your code twice in `group by` clause and in `select`. You can easily switch cte to subquery, but I think cte is much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
with cte as (
   select
       (year(OrderDate) / 5) as y, Orders
   from orders
)
select count(*) as No_Of_Orders,
  CAST(y * 5 AS nchar(4)) + N' - ' + CAST(y * 5 + 4 AS nchar(4)) AS Year_Range, 
  sum(Orders) Total_Price
from cte
group by FLOOR(YEAR(y)/5),y
```

Output:

```
NO_OF_ORDERS    Year_Range  Total_Price
---------------------------------------
4               1995 - 1999     2101
1               2000 - 2004     700
1               2005 - 2009     400
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17b59/1)</kbd>

Comment: how's that different from my answer?